# How to initialize an array with 2 columns but undefined number of lines on python?

Tags: python

i would like to initialize an empty array with 2 columns which i could add new lines to the array later.

I have this code :

```
import numpy as np
import statistics as st
import pyswarms as ps
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier


def load_input():
dados = np.array([])
for x in range(1,22):
        fich = np.loadtxt("%d.csv" %x,delimiter=",");
        aux = []
        valor = 5.0;
        for y in range(0,len(fich)):
            if fich[y][0] <= valor :
                aux.append(fich[y,1])
                aux.append(fich[y,2])
                aux.append(fich[y,3])
            else:
                dados = np.vstack((dados,np.array([st.mean(aux),x])));
                dados = np.vstack((dados,np.array([st.stdev(aux),x])));
                y = y-1;
                aux[:] = []
                valor = valor + 5;
   return dados
```

But when i run the code i get this error :

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly.
```

I think the error is coming after i try to add new row to the array. How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use np.stack() instead of np.vstack() as vstack is deprecated per docs: [https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html]

Use a normal python array for dados and append into it, then call np.stack() after you've constructed your array.

Comment: sorry, i dont understand. A "normal python array" is like this  || dados = np.array([]) || ?

Comment: dados = []  Then at the end use something like dados = np.stack(dados) Numpy arrays are a 'special' type.